# Get parameters in HttpServerRequest

Tags: java, vert.x

While using `HttpServerRequest` in `io.vertx.core.http` java, I use this method:

```
 default String getParam(String paramName) {
    return params().get(paramName);
  }
```

to get the params of the received request. When one of the parameters begins with `+`, I mean plus sign, the returned value does not have `+` .

```
 var number = request.getParam("number");
```

Any solution? thanks.

```
/v1/services?number=+12345
```

or

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8080/v1/services?number=+12345'
```

in this example, the returned value is 12345 which is not my desired one. I need `+12345`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

`+` sign must be [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding):

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8080/v1/services?number=%2B12345'
```